# Add an SSH key on boot

Tags: ssh, git, key-authentication, rc

I have a Git repo that is authenticated with an SSH key - the key is not the standard `id_rsa`.

I can run:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add /home/forge/.ssh/otherkey
```

Then

```
git pull origin master
```

This is working.

The server needs to do a git pull on boot.

So I have code in `rc.local` that pull the repo it's working only when the key is default `id_rsa` but not when the key is different.

If I add it in bashrc then it does add the key and work when I log in, but not immediately from boot.

How can I add an alternative SSH key than id_rsa for git to use, that can be instantiated before my git pull command in `rc.local`?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add ssh key file using ssh config.

Here is default for all users `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` 
Here is for current user `~/.ssh/config`

Example of current user ssh config per host:

```
## Home nas server ##
Host nas01
     HostName 192.168.1.100
     User root
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/nas01.key

## Login AWS Cloud ##
Host aws.apache
     HostName 1.2.3.4
     User wwwdata
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.apache.key
```

[You can read more here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/)

Comment: Yep that's worked perfectly - I was overcomplicating things. Thanks for your help!